# IP remains unchanged

Tags: python, proxy, ip, tor

I am trying to connect to Tor by code and change my identity. The results that I have gotten so far are that I connect successfully but can't change my identity. Here is my code :

```
import socket
import socks
import httplib

def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"127.0.0.1",9150,True)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def newIdentity():
    socks.setdefaultproxy()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1",9151))   
    s.send("AUTHENTICATE\r\n")

    response = s.recv(128)

    if response.startswith("250"):
        s.send("SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n")

    s.close()    
    connectTor()

def showIP():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-ip.herokuapp.com")
    conn.request("GET","/")
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print (response.read())

def main():
    connectTor()    
    print("Connected to Tor")    
    showIP()    

    print("Hew Id is")
    newIdentity()
    showIP()

main()
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: But I don't think it creates a new identity and that is the purpose of my code, and also where the error is.

Comment: Either I am reading your code wrong or I haven't explained my goal properly. The code I have posted does change my IP but only once. I need it to connect to Tor do something, change my IP again, do the same thing, change my IP yet again and so on. In your code I dont see the equivalent of my "newIdentity" function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a unix based OS you can use subprocess and killall with [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGHUP)  to create a new identity:

```
url = 'http://my-ip.heroku.com'
import socks
import socket
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import requests
res = requests.get(url)
response = res.content
print(response)

from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["killall","-HUP", "tor"])

res = requests.get(url)
response = res.content
print(response)

In [2]: paste
url = 'http://my-ip.heroku.com'
import socks
import socket
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import requests
res = requests.get(url)
response = res.content
print(response)

from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["killall","-HUP", "tor"])

res = requests.get(url)
response = res.content
print(response)

## -- End pasted text --
94.242....

95.130....
```

Comment: When I run your code I get `tor(5261): Operation not permitted
tor: no process found` and hence `ubprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['killall', '-HUP', 'tor']' returned non-zero exit status 1` Do you know why?

Comment: @Rojas, yep because you have not started tor