# New identity with TOR and Stem

Tags: python, tor, stem

Stem officials [docs](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) says that new identity is established by the following:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

And below is my code:

```
import urllib2

from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def connect():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(my_pass)  
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

for i in range(5):
    connect()
    print urllib2.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com/').read().strip()
```

However the ip address does not change.

ps. Yes, I've edited the `torrc` file.

p2. I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887505/how-to-change-tor-identity-in-python) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-programmatically/33726166) threads.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656298/ip-remains-unchanged/27657475#27657475

Comment: What is your code to make urllib use Tor's SOCKS proxy?  Right now it looks like it should just be using your regular internet connection.

Comment: You're using urllib2 with your real IP and not through tor, you need to set the proxy

Answer (score 3):

you will have to wait until a new nym is available:

`if controller.is_newnym_available():
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)`